# Simple.Mocking, how to expect any IEnumerable as parameter?

Tags: c#, mocking

I'm testing `Simple.Mocking` and wonder how to expect any `IEnumerable<MyModel>` in my mock?

In my interface:

```
void Remove(IEnumerable<MyModel> enumerable);
```

and in my test:

```
Expect.MethodCall(() => service.Remove(???));
```

What should I write instead of ??? to expect any paramters except null?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to work!

```
Any<IEnumerable<MyModel>>.Value.AsInterface
```